# Can't change instance attribute of my class?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm starting out in python and I can't quite figure out why I'm unable to change the data stored in one of my instance attributes. I have the following code:

```
class Bank:

def __init__(self, bank = 'Unnamed'):
    self.bank = bank
    self.clients = []
    self.status = {'bank': self.bank, 'clients': self.clients}
    self.c_counter=0

def deposit(self, name = None, amount = 200):
    self.name = name
    self.amount = amount
    self.c_counter += 1

    if self.name is None:
        self.name = print("client" + str(self.c_counter));
        self.clients.append((self.name, self.amount))
    else:
        self.clients.append((self.name, self.amount))
```

This produces the following output:

```
bb = Bank("bb")
bb.deposit(amount = 2000)
bb.status

out: {'bank': bb, 'clients': [(None, 2000)]}
```

While the desired output is:

```
out: {'bank': bb, 'clients': [('client1', 2000)]}
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to do is to set the client name to "clientx" if client name is not specified during a deposit; the x is just a number to distinguish each generic client from other generic clients without a specific name.

If a specific name is not provided when calling the deposit attribute of the bank the client name is set to `None` by default. I check this with the if condition and change the client name accordingly, but for some reason the client name literally gets added as "None" to the list of clients in the dictionary (list of tuples). What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` prints a string to `sys.stdout` and returns `None`. you should change the line

```
self.name = print("client" + str(self.c_counter));
```

to

```
self.name = "client" + str(self.c_counter)
```

or maybe `self.name = f"client{self.c_counter}"` for python >= 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a `NoneType`, it's `None` and you can prove it:

```
>>> type(print())

<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

And:

```
>>> print(print())

None
>>>
```

So `print` isn't be used for assigning, `print` is used for outputting stuff, whereas in this case you're assigning stuff, that which isn't meant for `print` to handle, so change:

```
self.name = print("client" + str(self.c_counter));
```

To:

```
self.name = "client" + str(self.c_counter)
```

Or:

```
self.name = "client%s" % self.c_counter
```

Or:

```
self.name = "client{}".format(self.c_counter)
```

Or if your python version is bigger or equal to 3.6, you can use:

```
self.name = f"client{self.c_counter}"
```